# inner function does not have right reference. I understand why, but i dont know JS to rework it so it works correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am creating an array of functions such as this.  The **url** in the array is correct, but when i finally loop through this information in the arraylist.... the funt at **x[1]** references the last value stored into **url** while at the same time, **x[0]** is correct.  Is there a way to adjust the inner *url* to match that of the **x[0]**?  I was thinking to put in a param to the anon-function but i wasnt sure that was going to work.  I also wasnt sure if i could work myself up the data tree, and be like function.parent[0] referencing the parent of the function and calling element 0.  I guess that last idea was sort of thinking in a DOM way of logic.

```
var newArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<fileUrls.length;++i) {
        var url = fileUrls[i];
        var x = [];//new Array();
        x = [url,
            function(){
                displayFile(url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
            }, 
            function(e){
                if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
                alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
                MA.hideMessage();
            }
        ];
        newArray.push(x);
    }
   pollingThrottler(2,newArray, function(a,b,c){ 
            //alert(a+"\n-----\n"+b+"\n-----\n"+c);
            //alert(bentleyPlugins.createThumbnailForPath(a,b,c));
            //alert(a);
                            //a does not reference the correct item.
            createThumbnailForPath(a,b,c);
            return;
        },function(){
            alert("success!");
        });
```

**is the actual code.**

Comment: You need to show the actual code, looks like you cut stuff out that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a generator function for your array elements like this:

```
function genElement( url ) {
 return [url,
  function(){
    displayFile(url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
  }, 
  function(e){
    if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
    alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
    MA.hideMessage();
  }
 ];
}    
arrayList.push( genElement( myUrl ) );
```

Basically what happens in your code is, that all function elements will reference the same `url` variable, which changes its values over the course of the loop.

When you use the generator function a copy of the url will be generated, when you call the generator function. This results in every element having its "own" url variable to reference.

**EDIT**

For the sake of easy to read code and performance, however, I would advise the answer of @dystroy as this is the better way to do such things in my opinion.

Comment: are you allowed to create a function in a function in such a way as to make it local, similar to how you can have classes in classes?   If so, i will define it right above the forloop as it is only ever used here.

Comment: @Fallenreaper It is perfectly fine to define functions inside other functions. They can then just be referenced inside the function scope they are defined in (unless a reference is exported).

Comment: @Sirko i just figured that out.  I wasnt sure how scope was for JS.... as you can see with this problem.  THanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use arrays but object oriented javascript :

```
function Thing(url) {
    this.url = url;
}
Thing.prototype.display = function(){
 displayFile(this.url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
};
Thing.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
    alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
    MA.hideMessage();
};
```

Then you can call

```
arrayList.push(new Thing(url));
```

and then `x.display()` will use the correct url.

[Here's a good practical reading about OOP in javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

EDIT :

Here's a supplementary method to get the needed array/object :

```
Thing.prototype.asArray = function(){
   var _this = this;
   return [this.url, function(){_this.display()}, this.doSomething];
}
```

But it starts to be less clear...

Comment: From a previous discussion I had, I think OP needs Arrays because he was using each Array to hold the arguments to a function call that is invoked later with `.apply`.

Comment: It still would be cleaner, in my opinion, to make this call either using a method of Thing or to build this array just in time when using `apply`.

Comment: Sadly, this approach is currently outside the scope of what i want to accplish.